# My shower drain is epoxied, what do I do to get the drain out?

Tags: shower, bathroom-fixtures, epoxy, stuck, drains

My prefab shower drain that screws in is glued with epoxy that was used to put the tile down. I've had to remove the tile and now the drain is stuck. How can I get the drain to screw down without ruining it?

The person who tiled my shower put the tile under the drain so the drain sat on top of the tile. It couldn't drain all the water. Now I have to re-tile it, but regular mortar or mastic will not stick to the shower base (*RediTile brand*), so an epoxy that came with the base was used.

[image]

Comment: "*How can I get the drain to screw down without ruining it?*" does that mean you had it out?  It appears not, as it has not been cleaned up. Epoxy? Are you sure, it looks like thinset or mastic.

Comment: I assume you want the drain lower so that you can tile around it? In that case, why not raise the level of the tiles a little instead with a thin layer of mortar all around before laying them?

Comment: He is dealing with existing tile, already lain.

Comment: @DAS - quote from the question: "I've had to remove the tile and ..." & "Now I have to re-tile it, but ..." - seems pretty clear to me that the existing tile has been removed and no new tiles have yet been placed.

Comment: Thanks. I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured it out and got my drain removed. Yes, it was epoxy. This is a RediTile pan that came with it's own epoxy because mortar or mastic doesn't work with this brand. I used Acetone and rubbed it around the drain until the epoxy became soft and I was able to get it out and clean it up. It only took a few seconds to get it out!